# Warning ElasticsearchDeprecationWarning: this request accesses system indices

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have an Warning when trying to get all indexes in Elastic after the last version update.

my Warning.

> C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\base.py:190:
> ElasticsearchDeprecationWarning: this request accesses system indices:
> [.apm-agent-configuration, .apm-custom-link, .kibana_1, .kibana_2,
> .kibana_task_manager_1, .kibana_task_manager_2,
> .kibana_task_manager_3], but in a future major version, direct access
> to system indices will be prevented by default
> warnings.warn(message, category=ElasticsearchDeprecationWarning)

Occurs when I do

```
for index in es.indices.get('*'):
```

Elasticsearch version 7.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deprecation warning lets you know that, in future versions, system indices (whose names start with a dot) won't be accessible; in case you'd been relying on this behavior.

See [System Indices #50251](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/50251).

The tl;dr is that system indices will be hidden because they shouldn't be exposed to the user.